# Getting External Data from Oracle to O365?

Tags: bcs, external-content-type, external-list, metadata, external-data

We have an on-premise oracle database with customer info (lets say roughly 10,000 rows), that we need to make available in our SharePoint Online (2013) environment in O365.

The requirement is that the data be re-usable anywhere in our SharePoint tenancy, so we would need to reference this customer info (read only) in all of our site collections.

Being new to these type of interfaces, what are the best options for accomplishing this?

Much appreciation in advance!

Comment: Will this be a hybrid solution (on premise SharePoint Server with a BDC to Oracle, and SharePoint Online connected to on premise SP), or a cloud only connection? [Deploy a Business Connectivity Services cloud-only solution in SharePoint 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj943762.aspx)

Comment: This would be a cloud only connection.  We have no on-premise sharePoint.  Currently, we are not leveraging any external facing web services and most of our data and business systems are behind our local firewall which requires VPN to hit.

Comment: Brent, I am also looking for a same system.
Did you find a way of doing it ?

Comment: Ahmed, we are building an on-premise OData web service and using materialized views to access our data.  From SharePoint we are using Business Connectivity Services (BCS) to connect to our web service.  This makes the data viewable as a SharePoint list or selectable as a column of metadata.  The limitations are the SharePoint call to the web service can only return a maximum of 5000 items at once, so we have to use some creative paging/filtering to make sure that the amount of data returned does not exceed 5000 at one time or you get an error.  Recommend reading/watching Fabian Williams stuff